# union all and sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

table 1

```
mmsi   type   l   w   flag   value
123    456    A   B   C      37
236    567    X   Y   Z      28
```

table 2

```
mmsi   type   l   w   flag   value
123    456    A   B   C      30
234    567    X   Y   Z      20
```

and I want to run a query to get unique values and for each row the sum of values stored in  the last field:

table final

```
mmsi   type   l   w   flag   value
123    456    A   B   C      67
234    567    X   Y   Z      20
236    567    X   Y   Z      28
```

How can I do it? I am trying with UNION ALL and SUM

```
SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", "value", SUM ("value")
FROM (SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", "value" FROM "table 1" UNION ALL
SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", "value" FROM "table 2") as def
GROUP BY "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", "value"
```

but this give me the following wrong result:

```
mmsi   type   l   w   flag   value  sum
123    456    A   B   C      37     37
123    456    A   B   C      30     30
234    567    X   Y   Z      20     20
236    567    X   Y   Z      28     28
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `value` from the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", SUM("value")
FROM (SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", "value" FROM "table 1" 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", "value" FROM "table 2"
     ) as def
GROUP BY "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag";
```